# c++11 variadic template method completely shadow base class method?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, variadic-functions

I have the following problem( see code below).

In a class that inherits from a base class, I want to be able to have two implementations of `operator()`. One that takes integers, one that takes "indices", see simple `Index` class.
The `operator(ints...)` will be in the child class, while I need to have the `operator(Index...)` in the parent class (also with different return type.)

The code below is not the exact design but a minimal working example explaining the final problem.

Problem is, if I put `operator(Index...)` in the child class, everything is good. If I put it in the base class, i get a compilation error:

```
error: no match for call to ‘(Tensor<1, int>) (Index<'i'>&)’
```

when I call `vec(i)` and the end of the `main()`. I understand the compiler doesn't find the good method, but why ? Is there some "shadowing" rule associated to variadic templates ?

Thanks !

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<char i>
class Index{
public:
    Index(){};
};

template<int order, typename T, class tensor_type>
class Tensor_traits{
  public:

      //// here, doesn't compile ! !
    //template <char i>
    //T&operator()(Index<i> &ii){
    //std::cout << "puet" << std::endl;
    //}
};


template<int order, typename T>
class Tensor : public Tensor_traits<order, T, Tensor<order, T>> {
    private:
    int data[3] = {1,2,3};
    public:
    Tensor(){};

    template <typename... Idx>
        typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Idx...,int>::value
        or std::is_same<Idx...,unsigned int>::value
        or std::is_same<Idx...,size_t>::value, T&>::type
        operator()(const Idx&... idx){
        return data[0]; //dummy here, actually i do other stuff !
        }

    // here, works!
    template <char i>
        T&operator()(Index<i> &ii){
        std::cout << "puet" << std::endl;
        }

};


int main() {

    Tensor<1,int> vec1;

    std::cout<< vec1(1) << std::endl;;

    Index<'i'> i;

    vec1(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding

```
using Tensor_traits<order, T, Tensor<order, T>>::operator();
```

or (suggested by Yakk (thanks) to have `Base` for other uses)

```
using Base = Tensor_traits<order, T, Tensor<order, T>>;
using Base::operator();
```

in `Tensor`

The problem isn't that the base class is a template class; the problem is that the derived class define another `operator()` method function that hide the `operator()` method inherited.

To verify this, delete the `operator()` defined in the derived class and you can see that, also without `using`, you can use the `operator()` of the base class.

Using `using` unhide the `operator()` of the base class, when an `operator()` is defined in the derived class, so you can use both.

Comment: Myself, I'd first do `using Base=Tensor_traits<order, T, Tensor<order, T>>;` then `using Base::operator();`.  Because my brain isn't smart enough to instantly prove `Tensor_traits<order, T, Tensor<order, T>>` is just the base of `Tensor<order,T>`, and by naming it `Base` the intention is more clear.

Comment: @Yakk - also to avoid code duplication in case of `using` for multiple base methods?

Comment: and in constructors etc.  If it wasn't CRTP, what I usually do is do that within the template arguement list as `,class Base =  Tensor_traits<order, T, Tensor<order, T>>`, but with CRTP that doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, it does work. But why does it hide it ? The arguments are different. I had tried to delete the operator() in the derived class and saw it was correctly calling for the one in the base class, but still ?